# WordPress How To Change My Header Depending On The Category

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, header

I am trying to change my header depending on the category. I have tried the id and the slug and for some reason it is not working. There must be something wrong with my method. I am using a if else statement.

```
if ( is_category('6') ) {
get_header( 'news' );}
else {
get_header();
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if ( is_category('news') ) {
get_header( 'news' );}
else {
get_header();
}
```

My header is named header-news.php
I was using the info from this page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page

Any help would be appreciated.

I am changing the single.php
I did first try calling the header-news.php first to make sure it works and it did, my if else statement seems to be wrong.

Comment: Are you in the loop? In any case, your code does seem correct, please provide more detail (like the whole single.php) -- Oops, it isn't, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_category` is intended for archive pages; `in_category` is for use within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the answer to this is to use:
 in_category

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/in_category

I changed the code to read:

```
if (in_category( 'news' ) ) {
get_header( 'news' );}
else {
get_header();
}
```

It worked perfectly!